# How to concatenate columns for multiple rows simultaneously in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I have the following 3 rows of data in cells `A1:A3` in Google Sheets:

```
Doe, Jane
Doe, Joe
John Doe
```

I want the following in `B1:B3`:

```
Jane Doe
Joe Doe
John Doe
```

Essentially, I'm creating a new column with all names as `FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME`.

My approach was to use `split`,`index`,`concatenate`,`find`,`isnumber`,and`if`, which works if I apply the function individually to each single cell:

```
= IF( ISNUMBER( find(",",A1)), concatenate(index(split(A1,", "),0,2)," ", index(split(A1,", "),0,1)),A1))
```

However, I want to repeat this function for each name in Column A using a single function in `B1`.

I tried to simply use `ArrayFormula`, but this (unsurprisingly) does not have the desired result:

```
= Arrayformula(IF( ISNUMBER( find(",",A1)), concatenate(index(split(A1,", "),0,2)," ", index(split(A1,", "),0,1)),A1)))
```

Resulting in:

```
JaneJoeDoe DoeDoeJohn
JaneJoeDoe DoeDoeJohn
John Doe
```

I'm too new to Google Sheets to know if there's a looping type approach to doing this. In `R`, I would have this figured out in 15 seconds using an `apply` function.

Comment: Please let me know if this would be better asked at StackOverflow...

Comment: You'd have to use python for this, or maybe javascript. Im not sure how a formula could differentiate first and last name (unless you want to write thousands of if else statements)

Comment: @Datanovice well just one `if else` statement I think: if a comma is present, the cell contains last then first name; otherwise the names are first followed by last. So far (I believe anyway), that's not my problem. My questions is really meant to focus on a way to essentially create a function that applies over many cells (each individually) in a loop...

Comment: you could use =query() for this and apply SQL syntax over a range of cells to apply your logic. It's not the same as a for loop, but the only way to apply a for loop in google sheets if by using the app script. Although I may be wrong...!

Comment: Hmm ok. I'll have to take an afternoon to learn SQL. So `query` is a sheets function, by the SQL syntax would still be written within a cell in the sheet directly?

Comment: It would run in one cell but return the range you're querying, if you had A2:C9 selected for example, it would return that range, if you added a where clause which was only present in two cells it would return two. Check out coding is for losers, he has really good Google query guides.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

As we've have found, it's not difficult to write a formula to achieve this outcome. But an `ARRAYFORMULA` is another matter and it seems (famous last words!) that it easier said than done (assuming even that it is possible).

I've looked at a solution using a script. The code follows the same process as the formula shown in the question.

- Establishes the last row in the column,
- Loops through each row,
- Gets the cell value, tests with a `SPLIT`, if there's a comma then we switch the names around; if not, we just use the name as-is,
- Paste the name into the cell on the same row but in the adjacent column.

---

```
function getlast(){

  // set the active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // get the last row in column A
  var Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

  // start loop for each row/name
  for (var x=1; x<(Alast+1); x++) {

    // get the value of the cell
    var values = sheet.getRange(x, 1).getValue();

    // slit the cell and then measure the length
    var mysplit = values.split(",");

    // if the length = 2, then there's a comma
    // so we need to switch the names around
    if (mysplit.length == 2){

      // set variables and values
      var firstname = mysplit[1].trim();
      var lastname = mysplit[0].trim();
      var myname = firstname+" "+lastname;

      // declare an array and then assign the name
      var newname = [];
      newname.push(myname);

    }
    else
    {
      // there's no comma so no need to switch around the names
      var myname = mysplit;

      // declare an array and then assign the name
      var newname = [];
      newname.push(myname);

    }

    // paste the new name - note the offset ( same row, but over one column
    sheet.getRange(x, 1).offset(0, 1).setValues([newname]); 

  }  

}
```

---

This screenshot shows the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(REGEXREPLACE({
 IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, " ")), ",$"), , IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, " "))),
 IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, " ")), ",$"),   IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, " ")), )},
 ",$", )), , 999^99))))
```

[image: 0]